# Internet Explorer 7/8/9 : IFRAME invisible

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I am trying to create an iframe for the following url.
http://www.pgsoftwaresolutions.in/index.html

```
<iframe src="http://www.pgsoftwaresolutions.in/index.html" width="255" height="210"></iframe>
```

I tried it on IE7 locally and IE 8/9 on browserstack.com
The page loads the timer works correctly when loaded directly in the IE browser, but when in an IFRAME it becomes invisible.

At first i thought that it might a jQuery issue or IE bug about IFRAME not triggering the document ready/load event.

Just to test what went wrong where in the javascript i added a javascript alert() in the javascript function which replaces the numbers on the timer on a copy of the above code in
http://www.pgsoftwaresolutions.in/debug/index.html

NOTE: To close this page after the first 7 alerts are fired. Quickly press ENTER and then CTRL + F4 to close the page.

I tested it on IE 7. It works and a series of alerts are fired at the start and then one every second.

Then i loaded the same page in an IFRAME and it DOES throw the alerts.

```
<iframe src="http://www.pgsoftwaresolutions.in/debug/index.html" width="255" height="210"></iframe>
```

I have no clue how to debug anything related to javscript or IFRAMEs on IE7 properly as Firebug lite does not support those so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your styles.css.

Remove `html{ position:relative; }` and your iframe will display in IE7 and higher.

Comment: Thats weird, but it worked :) thanks..
I had tried changing the frameborder property on the iframe to see if i can see it.. when i didnt see the border in IE i thought it might be a bug in IE and not something related to css.
Do you know any way to debug IE like firebug for firefox?
I mean in firefox firebug allows to inspect contents of the iframe.

Comment: Well you can use FireBug Lite for IE, but I like you said before I don't think it's quite as robust as the one for FireFox.  I do believe that this is a bug in IE and not anything wrong with your css.

Why did you set html, body positioning anyway?