# Using iframe in windows 8 Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, iframe, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am using an iframe, but for some reason in windows 8 and 8.1 it is not working properly.

I tested with Browserstack and it is working fine in most all browsers, but in Windows 8 and 8.1 using Internet Explorer, **nothing inside the iframe is clickable**. I read that there's a [webview element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx) alternative for Windows 8, but I believe that only concerns Windows apps, not websites.

The strange thing is when opening the IE developer tools and clicking the inspect element button on the iframe, it all of a sudden works.

[image: works with ie inspect element developer tools]

I saw a somewhat situation [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150841/internet-explorer-7-8-9-iframe-invisible). It seems like it must be some sort of css positioning issue, but I'm not sure.

I also tested the iframe url [directly](https://www.bandpage.com/extension/tour?bid=592400576134819840&dest=www.bandpage.com%2Fextension&dest_id=cb12e19c-fed8-4263-bb1f-5d62fefc43ed&width=810&height=370&opacity=100&layout=&theme=light&font=Montserrat&includetitle=true&includeshowheader=false&extensiontype=tour&bandbid=592400576134819840&extbid=595489132478730240&cid=rm-transport-0#http://lonesomehighwaymusic.com) in windows 8 and it works fine when doing that.

So to recap this occurs in **only Windows 8** and **Windows 8.1** and only in Internet Explorer. Firefox, opera, and chrome all were fine.

Thanks for any help here! I thought my days of dealing with IE issues were over for the most part after they decided [end support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) for legacy browsers, but I guess I was wrong!

By the way the website is http://lonesomehighwaymusic.com

Comment: Are you embedding the iframe in an SSL secured page?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the site before http://lonesomehighwaymusic.com. It's not using ssl, but I believe the iframe is.

Comment: Do you have any helpful outputs in the "console" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the issue. It's in the CSS.
https://u.bandpagecdn.net/rootmusic-static/css/widgets/show.Montserrat.1459446234.122.css

```
.scroll-container {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

Just remove it!

Comment: Genius! How on earth did you figure that out? Do you have a windows 8 computer? What do you use to debug? The ie dev console is pretty miserable to use in my opinion. It was pretty time consuming just trying to test that using the Browserstack, I praise you for even attempting to figure that out.

Comment: Ha the only problem now is that it's css from the iframe so I can't exactly remove it! I tried contacting Bandpage(now owned by google) last week about this and they never responded. Oh well!

Comment: Apparently they [don't support IE](http://help.bandpage.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1537384-why-we-don-t-support-internet-explorer) so I doubt they'll fix this. Pretty stupid though since it's such a simple fix. I'm curious Gerfried, do you have any idea why this occurs? I checked [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) and there's no documented info about transform not working in IE.

Comment: My only idea to this is to play around with IE's compatibility mode. Afaik the compatibility mode settings of your main site will be inherited to all iframes. Try to add this in your head section of your main site: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">

Comment: Yes, I have Windows 8.1 with IE11. If you are used to work with the Debugger it's quite easy. I moved the mouse over a link and always the whole .scroll-container was marked blue - so I saw it was overlapping the link somehow. Then I just switched on and off its style properties.

Comment: Aren't you able to add your own stlyes in the admin area of Bandpage? Usually such plugins can be stlyed a bit. If so overwrite the default style with .scroll-container {-ms-animation: none !important;}